# error when i want to save java file in jdk/bin

Tags: windows-7

when i save java file error is you dont have permission to save in this location contact the administrator to obtain permission on window7

Answer (score 2):

Don't store application data in the "Program Files" directory.

It is very bad design and regular users don't have write access to that directory (for a **very** good reason).

So even if you changed your settings locally to open up the door for viruses your application won't run on other computers.

Besides: storing a Java file in the JDK directory serves no purpose at all.

Btw: your uppercase letters are broken, as well as the dot or the comma...

Answer (score 1):

That's normal - `jdk/bin` is the installation directory of the JDK, regular users cannot (and should not) write files there. You'll have the same problem on Linux/Unix and on Mac OS X, where installation directories are off-limits to regular users.

Write your files to the users home directory (System property "user.home", works across platforms), or let the user choose where you save stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Bin directory do not allow directly to save program in it.
it is so simple, just save your .java file on desktop and then copy paste it in Bin. done ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the file can't save directly to `c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0\bin\`

**Solution:-**

Click start Menu type Notepad command in run [run as administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3ljL.jpg)

Right click the Notepad run as Administrator, then type the program file can save directly to `c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0\bin\`

Just try it......